# An error occurred while running Cordova in ionic 2

Tags: ios, macos, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing a Hybrid app using `ionic 3` but when I build the app in IOS I'm getting below error.

```
Error
at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

[ERROR] An error occurred while running Cordova build iOS (exit code 1).

> My ionic environment info

```
  cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
    Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.4 
    Node       : v8.1.4
    npm        : 5.0.3 
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b 

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```